# re-bind href tag on click

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to Ember and I work on big legacy project. The issue is that URI `fooUri` in the following template is bound only once and `fooUri` stays the same:

```
<a {{bind-attr href=fooUri}}>
    <span class="appicon-table appicon"></span>
</a>
```

Controller code:

```
App.barController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    . . .
    fooUri: function() {
        var fooOptions = $.extend({}, this.model.foo.options);
        . . .
        var querystring = encodeURIComponent($.param(fooOptions));
        var uri = '#' + router.generate( ..., querystring, ...);
        return uri;
    }.property('fooMeasureId'),
    . . .
})
```

E.g. I need uri will be recalculated each time I click on link because `this.model.foo.options` is changed.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Ember are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.model.foo` is an ember object it is observable. So you would add it as a dependency to your `.property()` call:

```
}.property('fooMeasureId', 'model.foo.options')
```

But then make sure to modify it with the Ember `.set()` and not with a simple assignment (`=`).

If it isn't an Ember.Object you have to manually call [`notifyPropertyChange`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange) on your `fooUri` computed property.